How do I make sure that my table headers aligns with my table data in a nested html table?
For context, I need a nested table to group table data (by pdo, program, location). The problem is my th does not aligned with my nested td when the columns are not fully expanded. I'm using Angular 14 and I made sure that my th and td have the same width using [style.width.px]="columnWidths[i]".
When columns not fully expanded, th and td does not aligned


Component.html
<div class="container-parent overflow-auto">
  <table #parentTable class="table-hover table-parent w-100">
    <thead>
      <tr class="th-row">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders; let i = index">
          <th
            class="table-headers"
            *ngIf="i < 4"
            [ngClass]="{ 'sticky-left': i < 2 }"
            [style.display]="columns[i].visible ? '' : 'none'"
            [style.width.px]="columnWidths[i]"
          >
            <i
              class="material-icons align-middle"
              [style.cursor]="'pointer'"
              *ngIf="!columns[i + 1]?.visible && i < 3"
              (click)="toggleColumn(i, 'add')"
              >add_box</i
            >
            <i
              class="material-icons align-middle"
              [style.cursor]="'pointer'"
              *ngIf="columns[i + 1]?.visible"
              (click)="toggleColumn(i, 'remove')"
              >indeterminate_check_box</i
            >
            {{ header }}
          </th>
        </ng-container>
        <th class="table-headers" [style.width.px]="columnWidths[4]">
          {{ tableHeaders[4] }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngIf="currentIndex == 0">
        <!-- PDO ROW -->
        <tr class="pdo-row" *ngFor="let pdo of tableData">
          <!-- PDO NAME -->
          <td
            class="td-headers"
            class="pdo-name-column sticky-left"
            [style.width.px]="columnWidths[0]"
            [style.display]="columns[0].visible ? '' : 'none'"
          >
            {{ pdo.name ?? '-' }}
          </td>
          <td class="td-headers" [colSpan]="tableHeaders.length - 1">
            <table class="w-100 h-100">
              <!-- UNIT ITEM ROW -->
              <tr class="unit-item-row">
                <!-- UNIT ITEM -->
                <td
                  class="unit-item-column"
                  [style.width.px]="columnWidths[3]"
                  [style.display]="columns[3].visible ? '' : 'none'"
                >
                  {{ programLocations?.unit_of_item ?? '-' }}
                </td>
                <!-- NO. ITEM -->
                <td class="num-item-column" [style.width.px]="columnWidths[4]">
                  {{ pdo.num_of_items_pdo | number : '1.0-0' ?? '-' }}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="currentIndex == 1">
        <!-- PDO ROW -->
        <tr class="pdo-row" *ngFor="let pdo of tableData">
          <!-- PDO NAME -->
          <td
            class="td-headers"
            class="pdo-name-column sticky-left"
            [style.width.px]="columnWidths[0]"
            [style.display]="columns[0].visible ? '' : 'none'"
          >
            {{ pdo.name ?? '-' }}
          </td>
          <td class="td-headers" [colSpan]="tableHeaders.length - 1">
            <table class="w-100 h-100">
              <!-- PROGRAM ROW -->
              <ng-container
                *ngFor="
                  let program of pdo.pdo_programs;
                  let programIndex = index
                "
              >
                <tr class="program-row">
                  <!-- PDO PROGRAM -->
                  <td
                    class="pdo-program-column sticky-left"
                    [style.width.px]="columnWidths[1]"
                    [style.display]="columns[1].visible ? '' : 'none'"
                  >
                    {{ program.program ?? '-' }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table class="w-100 h-100">
                      <!-- UNIT ITEM ROW -->
                      <tr class="unit-item-row">
                        <!-- UNIT ITEM -->
                        <td
                          class="unit-item-column"
                          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[3]"
                          [style.display]="columns[3].visible ? '' : 'none'"
                        >
                          {{ programLocations?.unit_of_item ?? '-' }}
                        </td>
                        <!-- NO. ITEM -->
                        <td
                          class="num-item-column"
                          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[4]"
                        >
                          {{
                            program.num_of_items_program
                              | number : '1.0-0' ?? '-'
                          }}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </ng-container>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="currentIndex > 1">
        <!-- PDO ROW -->
        <tr class="pdo-row" *ngFor="let pdo of tableData">
          <!-- PDO NAME -->
          <td
            class="td-headers"
            class="pdo-name-column sticky-left"
            [style.width.px]="columnWidths[0]"
            [style.display]="columns[0].visible ? '' : 'none'"
          >
            {{ pdo.name ?? '-' }}
          </td>
          <td class="td-headers" [colSpan]="tableHeaders.length - 1">
            <table class="w-100 h-100">
              <!-- PROGRAM ROW -->
              <ng-container
                *ngFor="
                  let program of pdo.pdo_programs;
                  let programIndex = index
                "
              >
                <tr class="program-row">
                  <!-- PDO PROGRAM -->
                  <td
                    class="pdo-program-column sticky-left"
                    [style.width.px]="columnWidths[1]"
                    [style.display]="columns[1].visible ? '' : 'none'"
                  >
                    {{ program.program ?? '-' }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table class="w-100 h-100">
                      <!-- LOCATION ROW -->
                      <tr
                        class="location-row"
                        *ngFor="
                          let programLocations of program?.pdo_program_locations
                        "
                      >
                        <!-- PROGRAM LOCATION -->
                        <td
                          class="location-column"
                          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[2]"
                          [style.display]="columns[2].visible ? '' : 'none'"
                        >
                          {{ programLocations?.location?.name ?? '-' }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <table class="w-100 h-100">
                            <!-- UNIT ITEM ROW -->
                            <tr class="unit-item-row">
                              <!-- UNIT ITEM -->
                              <td
                                class="unit-item-column"
                                [style.width.px]="columnWidths[3]"
                                [style.display]="
                                  columns[3].visible ? '' : 'none'
                                "
                              >
                                {{ programLocations?.unit_of_item ?? '-' }}
                              </td>
                              <!-- NO. ITEM -->
                              <td
                                class="num-item-column"
                                [style.width.px]="columnWidths[4]"
                              >
                                {{
                                  pdo.num_of_items_pdo | number : '1.0-0' ?? '-'
                                }}
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </ng-container>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Grand total-->
      <tr class="grand-total-row font-weight-bold">
        <td
          class="grand-total-column sticky-left"
          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[0]"
          [style.display]="columns[0].visible ? '' : 'none'"
        >
          Grand total
        </td>
        <td
          class="grand-total-column sticky-left"
          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[1]"
          [style.display]="columns[1].visible ? '' : 'none'"
        ></td>
        <td
          class="grand-total-column"
          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[2]"
          [style.display]="columns[2].visible ? '' : 'none'"
        ></td>
        <td
          class="grand-total-column"
          [style.width.px]="columnWidths[3]"
          [style.display]="columns[3].visible ? '' : 'none'"
        ></td>
        <td class="grand-total-column" [style.width.px]="columnWidths[4]">
          {{ grandTotal.totalNumItems | number : '1.0-0' }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

Component.css
table,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 12px;
}
th:not(:first-child) {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}
.table-parent {
  min-width: 1440px;
}
.container-parent {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.grand-total-column:not(:first-child) {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.grand-total-column.sticky-left:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}
.pdo-name-column.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

/* .grand-total-column.sticky-left:nth-child(2),
.table-headers.sticky-left:nth-child(2),
.pdo-program-column.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 144px;
  background-color: white;
} */

.th-row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.pdo-row,
.program-row:not(:last-child),
.location-row:not(:last-child),
.unit-item-row:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.grand-total-row {
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.unit-item-column,
.grand-total-column:nth-child(4) {
  border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.table-headers:nth-child(5),
.num-item-column,
.grand-total-column:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: right;
}

th,
.pdo-name-column,
.pdo-program-column,
.location-column,
.beneficiary-column,
.currency-column,
.num-beneficiaries-column,
.funding-needs-column,
.grand-total-column {
  padding: 1px;
}

For sample demo, click here

@DarkBee SLR, I've included the view and css code. The MRE/demo is hosted and can be run on stackblitz.

The table layout algorithm allows browsers to deviate from cell widths you might have specified, unless you apply table-layout: fixed; to the table element.

I already tried that, but the No. of items column header does not aligned with its table data. This might be because td is nested https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pf19am?file=src%2Fapp%2Freports-table%2Freports-table.component.css`

Why are you nesting the tables like this?

I need to create a table where each row is grouped together by pdo, advocacy etc. like this one https://imgur.com/a/hxt5fcN . Hence, I used nested table.

I was able to fix this by using [style.min-width.px] instead of [style.width.px]. Using table-layout: fixed; makes the column not aligned
Sample demo

try changing ng-container to div,
and add "table-layout: fixed;" for table in css.
i hope this helps

thank you, but it does not work

So, a little bit of background, first off.
In your CSS, you have:
.table-parent {
  min-width: 1440px;
}

which means the table will always be at least 1440px wide.
Whenever you have a <table> that has a fixed width, by default (Which is table-layout: auto), the browser wants to make the <td>s bigger to fill the whole space, and so even though you gave your first <td> a width of width: 144px; using calculateColumnWidths(), the browser actually just uses that as a guideline, for resizing tables.
Now, the problem is that because of all this nested table business, we NEED to actually follow the width set by your calculateColumnWidths(), otherwise the whole thing is going to fall apart as width of each column is going to automatically be resized by the text inside that particular row, rather than the width you've set in JS.

Therefore, in order to prevent the browser from resizing the columns willy-nilly according to his own math calculations, we need to add:
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}

which will cause the browser to actually obey your widths set in calculateColumnWidths(), instead of trying to fill up the min-width:1440px  of your table however he can.
The alternative solution is, unfortunately, to remove your nested tables of your current code, and just use one table instead of a table inside a table inside a table.

table-layout: fixed does not work on nested tables. I got it aligned with [style.min-width.px] instead of [style.width.px]
